# What is the functional difference between cardio-pulmonary and the baroreceptors in the regulation of Blood pressure?

Tags: cardiology, physiology, cardiac-physiology

Guyton mentions two types of receptor- the baroreceptors and the cardiopulmonary receptors- that are involved in the maintenance of the acute changes in blood pressure. I just wanted to know how these two receptors might differ functionally, i.e. which one is triggered when a certain specific event occurs? 
According to Guyton:

> .. low- pressure receptors play an important role, especially in minimizing arterial pressure changes in response to changes in blood volume...

How is it that these (Cardio-pulmonary) receptors are significant when there is a change in volume? Is there some other physiological explanation to justify why these receptors are implicated in this scenario and not the Baroreceptors? If that is not the case, should I view both these systems as a single unit and that they both do the same function, albeit in a different region of the circulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[High-pressure baroreceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_pressure_receptors)** are in the part of the circulatory system with blood pressures higher than 60 mm Hg - in the aortic arc and in the carotid sinus at the bifurcation of the carotid artery. Their **activation by high blood pressure** results in **a decreased heart rate and vasodilation** and hence in a drop of blood pressure.

**[Low-pressure baroreceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_pressure_receptors)** are in the part of the circulatory system with pressures below 60 mm Hg - in the pulmonary arteries and right atria, among other. Their activation **by increased blood volume** (increased tension of the wall of the right atrium and pulmonary arteries) results in **a decreased secretion of the antidiuretic hormone, renin and aldosterone** and thus in **increased water excretion by the kidneys.**

So, the two types of baroreceptors are activated by different stimuli and have different effects.